# Tomcat 6 Eclipse root deployment

Tags: eclipse, tomcat6

I have a Java web application running on Tomcat6 built with Eclipse.  It has always been run in a subdirectory:

/webapps/appDIR

As a result, the URL is:

www.application.com/appDIR

I now want it to just be deployed to the top level.  I rename the directory to ROOT and extract the WAR.  Set the permissions, and it doesn't work.  It goes to an infinite redirect of the error page, and then the page dies.

I can rename the the directory to anything else and it works.  For example I could call it test, in which case the URL becomes:

www.application.com/test

.....works fine.  I just can't use "ROOT", which would allow the wwww.application.com URL to work.

I did some searching, and decided it was related to the context.xml file.  It is currently sitting in the /WEB-INF directory (wrong?), and it only contains an end tag of "" (more wrong?).  I moved that file to the /META-INF directory, and it didn't work.  I figured that maybe it couldn't be empty and I added the contents of the following link to it:

http://www.wellho.net/resources/ex.php4?item=a654/6_context.xml

And still no go.

Any ideas?  For a little more background, I'm now deploying it to Amazon's Beanstalk whereas before it was self hosted.  Beanstalk defaults to deploying to ROOT, and I didn't see a reason to fight them on it, whereas Eclipse feels differently.

Comment: I started down this path of trying to make it work out of the "ROOT" directory because of the infinite redirect from Amazon.  You would hit the base URL -- www.applicaion.com -- and in the access log you would see the session ID assigned, then the redirect to the error ~15 times in a row, then the web browser warning that there are too many redirects.

Again, this started because we were deploying the WAR file to a subdirectory, and now I want it at the base directory for Amazon Beanstalk.

Comment: Same behavior in local environment -- it wants to be deployed in a directory other that webapps/ROOT.  Here's the redirect error that happens:  The webpage at http://localhost:8080/login.do?errorCode=0 has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.

Comment: I'm starting to suspect the redirect setup.  In index.jsp, I have <c:redirect url="login.do" />, and then in the servlet mapping I have <prop key="/login.do">loginController</prop>.....

Comment: I looked into Spring, and I'm pretty sure that's not what's doing it.  I gave up and am using an Apache redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned: "Beanstalk defaults to deploying to ROOT, and I didn't see a reason to fight them on it".

If you care to fight -

A hack to be sure, but to get our app to deploy under a subdirectory, we did the following with a beanstalk config file (.ebextensions)

```
commands:
   # This modified the default beanstalk deploy script so that our WAR file sits in appropriate subdirectory.
   fixdeployscript:
      command: sed -i 's/webapps\/ROOT/webapps\/MyAppName/g' /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/03deploy.sh
```